# Virtuemart 3 модуль товара по производителю

Tags: php, virtuemart, модули

В стандартом наборе компонента Virtuemart есть модуль показа товара (Отображает Рекомендуемые товары, Лидеры продаж, Случайные товары или Новинки) есть фильтрация по категории, но нет фильтрации по производителю. Для решения задачи использовал шаблон вывода (product.php), задействовал поле ввода Текст колонтитула (текст после модуля). В этом поле буду писать имя производителя или любой другой критерий поиска в строке наименования (детский, санки, прутья). 
Прописываю такое условие в цикле

```
if( stripos($product->product_name,$footerText) ) {}
```

если $footerText латиница все работает отлично, но если это кириллица тогда показов товара не будет. Как я выяснил, кодировка у меня UTF-8. И сравнение на вхождение подстроки в строку должно проходить. Но нет.

И функция iconv не решает проблему. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Решилась проблема следующим образом:

- переменная преобразована в нужную кодировку

  ```
  $footerText_iconv = mb_convert_encoding($footerText, "UTF-8", "HTML-ENTITIES");
  $footerText_iconv = iconv("UTF-8","ISO-8859-1",$footerText_iconv);
  ```
- условие было не верное, вот так правильно:

  ```
  if( stripos($product->product_name,$footerText_iconv) !== false )
  ```

Если нужно сделать быстрый хак для стандартного модуля Vidtuemart вывода товара с определенным словом в наименовании товара (цвет, размер, имя производителя). Тогда это решение будет полезным.